# Creating python library with dynamic settings based on the source where I import it

Tags: python, python-3.x, shared-libraries, setup.py

I created a python library (pyhton3.7) with the following structure

```
- my_library:
  - module1
    -- file.py
  - module
  - settings.py
- setup.py
```

The settings.py file has some config constants like `API_URL='http://dev...'`, some classes location like `USER_CLASS=my_library.module1`

I would like when I import this library into an application to change the settings/py constant var dynamically based on my app settings.

Is there any clean way to do it? I saw DynaConf but it doesn't seem to be useful in this case.

Comment: Perhaps you could have a separate config (text file or whatever) and then settings.py will import the data from that config file.

Comment: I'm personnaly using ```import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))``` in my `__init.py__` files to be sure to import files from the parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible to do that using DynaConf.

Take a look at that part of "[working variables](https://dynaconf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/usage.html#working-environments)".

The config file can be of the following formats: `.toml`, `.py`, `.yaml` and `.json`

And still has support for `.env` files

Consider looking at the lib's CLI. It makes the job a lot easier:
https://dynaconf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/cli.html